# How to range users in 3 columns in every line, instead of on 1 column?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to range users on 3 columns in every line, instead of on 1?

Instead this:

```
User             
User
User
User
User
User
```

I need:

```
User User User
User User User
```

**view.rb**

```
 <%= content_tag_for :td, @users do |s| %><div id="f">
<td><pre> <%= image_tag(s.image, height: '45', width: '32') %> <%= link_to s.display_name, users_path(s.id)%></pre></td>
<br>                               
</div>
<% end %>
```

**controller.rb**

```
def p
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
  end
```

Comment: Why have you got `div` elements outside a `td`? should be `tr` not `div` or maybe there should be no `td` element at all

Comment: I dont't understand. Please introduce me your code, that elements will be arrangement like on arrangement I need on my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.in_groups_of(x)`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) is what you are looking for:

```
<table>
  <% @users.in_groups_of(3) do |users| %>
    <tr>
      <% users.each do |user| %>
        <td><%= user.try(:display_name) %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I used `user.try(:display_name)` because if `@users % 3 != 0`, you will end up with the last array filled with `nil`s.

Example:

```
User.limit(5).in_groups_of(3)
# returns
[
  [<User id:...>, <User id:...>, <User id:...>],
  [<User id:...>, <User id:...>, nil]
]
```

Comment: You can use `in_groups_if(3, false)` to prevent extra `nil`'s.

Comment: We do want extra `nil`s because a row has to contain 3 `td`s, not less, not more.

Comment: I have: user user user user user- to end the line e.t.c.

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of what you "have" and what you are expecting @user3642357 because I don't understand your comment

Comment: How insert css class in td? Name of css #st.

Answer (score 1):

[in_groups](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups) is your friend

```
<% @users.in_groups(3, false) do |users| %>
  <tr>
    <% users.each do |user| %>
      <td class="user"><%= user.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#in_groups`:

```
<tr>
  <% @users.in_groups(3).each do |groups_of_users| %>
    <td>
      <% groups_of_users.reject{ |u| u.nil? }.each do |user| %>
        <div><%= user.name %></div>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Oh, and switch to [Haml](http://haml.info). :) That turns this into:

```
%tr
  - @users.in_groups(3).each do |groups_of_users|
    %td
      - groups_of_users.reject{ |u| u.nil? }.each do |user|
        %div= user.name
```

Comment: equivalent for `.reject{ |u| u.nil? }`: `.select(&:present?)` ; Your code will display one `tr` with one `td`, containing 3 users' name => I think the asker wants `to range users on 3 columns in every line` (using his own words)

Comment: No, I'm using #in_groups, not #in_groups_of, so I'm splitting into 3 total groups. If the list of users was sorted alphabetically, my solution will keep the users in 3 alphabetically-sorted columns (at least for languages that read columns top-to-bottom, left-to-right).